# Is there a way to print only the first appearance of a subreport in Jasper-Report?

Tags: java, xml, jasper-reports, overflow

I'm fixing a Jasper-Report not being able to print the first page when a given parameter $P{} in a subreport is too big to fit into the page.

The report is pretty simple. A single template page with a title, pageheader, pagenumber, a subreport with just a few textFields( username, date, category...), and a datatable. This template is being repeated for every printed page until all table rows are printed. The only exception is the subreport which is printed only on the first page. This was done by **printWhenExpression** set to "$V{PAGE_NUMBER}==1", which seems to be the accepted solution everywhere I look.

This is the subreport definition:

```
    <subreport>
        <reportElement 
            positionType="Float" 
            stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="5" y="67" width="160" height="13" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" 
            isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" 
            uuid="33028395-a759-4029-83de-17fb8465fc3b">
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}==1]]></printWhenExpression>
        </reportElement>
        <subreportParameter name="username">
            <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{username}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
        </subreportParameter>
        <subreportParameter name="startdate">
            <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{startdate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
        </subreportParameter>
        <subreportParameter name="enddate">
            <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{enddate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
        </subreportParameter>
        <subreportParameter name="category">
            <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{category}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
        </subreportParameter>
        <subreportParameter name="selectedareas">
            <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{selectedareas}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
        </subreportParameter>
        <subreportParameter name="contract">
            <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{contract}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
        </subreportParameter>
        <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "userdata.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
    </subreport>
```

The problem is, when subreport parameter *$P{selectedAreas}* is too big to fit in one page, Jasper just renders a full blank first page. With nothing in it, none, not page headers, nothing. 
Second page and beyond appear just right.

If we **remove $V{PAGE_NUMBER}==1** then this error is thrown:

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Infinite loop creating new page due to page header overflow.

This is due the subreport using 2 pages, which aparrently makes the use of *printWhenExpression* as discriminator useless. Is there another way to print the subreport only for the first appearance?

Comment: I can't really understand, this subreport has dynamic height and is in a page header?. You probably need to do a [mcve], do it minimal!, including  both main report and subreport jrxml. As question is, at least for me it's impossible to give you advice on report design.

Comment: Yes, subreport has a dynamic height and is in a page header (in-between two always-repeating elements). I guess it wasn't meant to be long at all, but years have passed and now this happens. I will do an example as soon as I can. But I can smell that the solution will be to cut the pageheader into slices and make each one of them repeatable except for the subreport one.

Comment: Rather use a groupHeader, pageHeader have fixed size you can't have dynamic (overflowing height) content in it